# strip HTML tags without removing & - ampersand in Python

Tags: python, html

I am using the following to strip HTML tags in Python, but it is also removing & (ampersand) and I need them to stay.  Any ideas?

from HTMLParser import HTMLParser

```
class MLStripper(HTMLParser):
    def __init__(self):
        self.reset()
        self.fed = []
    def handle_data(self, d):
        self.fed.append(d)
    def get_data(self):
        return ''.join(self.fed)

def strip_tags(html):
    s = MLStripper()
    s.feed(html)
    return s.get_data()
```

(also, code blocks not cooperating, please imagine an indent on the last three lines)

Comment: Why do you want to keep `&` but not `<`? You should be **escaping** your text before concatenating it into HTML.

Comment: I fixed your code indentation for you. :)

Comment: Thanks for the help!  The reason is because I am reading in fields from a webpage and some of the fields contain & that need to stay (e.g. Nathan & Jones Law Firm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex substitution sounds like an easy way to do it.

```
import re
text = '<b>foo&bar <a href="http://www.example.com/">link</a></b>'
re.sub(r'<.+?>', '', text)
# foo&bar link
```

There might be some special cases I haven't thought about which would require a bit more complicated regex.

Comment: You are right, I have edited my answer with something even simpler.

Comment: Only issue I had which I am sure is simply because I am a relative NOOB is that I needed to set

    text = re.sub(...)

rather than just

    re.sub(...)